# Fix for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:Unexpected end of request content

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a .net core service fabric stateless service, which is working ok most of the time. But getting "System.AggregateException: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException" now and then. It is not consistent or proportional to load.

I don't see any pattern of when it's happening.

It didn't fix the issue and I am running out of places to look.

1. I tried to reproduce on heavy load - it didn't happen - So load related
2. I read about the data rate and tried the below code in startup

   services.Configure(options =>
   {
   options.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
   options.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = null;
   options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 100000000;
   });

above didn't fix the issue

3. Added middleware to see more info. Couldn't see anything useful so far.. all I am seeing is the one that reaches application layer

Comment: could it be that a caller of the service sends corrupted web requests?

Comment: Firing the same request again works. I wasn't really sure so ruled that out. Do you think it is possible for the client to corrupt one and not the next one? I will explore further in this aspect.